# Generate grpc-gateway, swagger and grpc-go files with bazel

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, workflow, bazel, grpc-gateway

I have a mono repo with some services (service-0 to service-4). There is a proto directory where are the proto files are stored. The proto-files are in the respective subfolders.
The directory is structured as followed:

```
.
├── BUILD.bazel
├── gateway
│   ├── .idea
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── gateway.iml
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── main.go
├── gen
│   └── pb-go
├── service-0
│   └── .idea
├── service-1
│   └── .idea
├── service-2
│   └── .idea
├── service-3
│   └── .idea
├── service-4
│   └── .idea
├── Makefile
├── proto
│   ├── service-0
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   │   └── service-0.proto
│   ├── service-1
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   │   └── service-1.proto
│   ├── service-2
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   │   └── service-2.proto
│   ├── service-3
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   │   └── service-3.proto
│   └── service-4
│       ├── BUILD.bazel
│       └── service-4.proto
├── README.md
├── scripts
│   └── generate-go.sh
├── test
├── ui
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── stdout.log
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── WORKSPACE
```

My Workspace file looks like this:

```
workspace(
    name = "tool",
    managed_directories = {"@npm": ["ui:node_modules"]},
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

## go rules
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    sha256 = "08369b54a7cbe9348eea474e36c9bbb19d47101e8860cec75cbf1ccd4f749281",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.0/rules_go-v0.24.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.0/rules_go-v0.24.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

## gazelle
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_gazelle",
    sha256 = "d4113967ab451dd4d2d767c3ca5f927fec4b30f3b2c6f8135a2033b9c05a5687",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.0/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.0/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:deps.bzl", "go_register_toolchains", "go_rules_dependencies")
load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies")

go_rules_dependencies()

go_register_toolchains()

gazelle_dependencies()

####### Protobuf rules
http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto_grpc",
    urls = ["https://github.com/rules-proto-grpc/rules_proto_grpc/archive/1.0.2.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "5f0f2fc0199810c65a2de148a52ba0aff14d631d4e8202f41aff6a9d590a471b",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto_grpc-1.0.2",
)

load("@rules_proto_grpc//:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_grpc_toolchains", "rules_proto_grpc_repos")
rules_proto_grpc_toolchains()
rules_proto_grpc_repos()
########

####### go grpc rules

load("@rules_proto_grpc//go:repositories.bzl", rules_proto_grpc_go_repos="go_repos")

rules_proto_grpc_go_repos()
#####################

################# GRPC-GATEWAY
load("@rules_proto_grpc//:repositories.bzl", "bazel_gazelle", "io_bazel_rules_go")

io_bazel_rules_go()

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:deps.bzl", "go_register_toolchains", "go_rules_dependencies")

go_rules_dependencies()

go_register_toolchains()

bazel_gazelle()

load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies")

gazelle_dependencies()

load("@rules_proto_grpc//github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway:repositories.bzl", rules_proto_grpc_gateway_repos="gateway_repos")

rules_proto_grpc_gateway_repos()

load("@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//:repositories.bzl", "go_repositories")

go_repositories()
###############################
```

The service-0.proto files has the following content:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto";

option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_swagger) = {
  info: {
    title: "Tool";
    version: "1.0";
    contact: {
      name: " Tool project";
      url: "https://gitlab.example.de/tool";
      email: "example@test.de";
    };
    license: {
      name: "Apache License 2.0";
      url: "https://gitlab.example.de/tool/-/blob/master/LICENSE";
    };
  };
  // Overwriting host entry breaks tests, so this is not done here.
  external_docs: {
    url: "https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway";
    description: "More about gRPC-Gateway";
  }
  schemes: HTTPS;
  consumes: "application/json";
  produces: "application/json";
  security_definitions: {
    security: {
      key: "Bearer";
      value: {
        type: TYPE_API_KEY;
        in: IN_HEADER;
        name: "Authorization";
      }
    }
  }
  responses: {
    key: "403";
    value: {
      description: "Returned when the user does not have permission to access the resource.";
    }
  }
  responses: {
    key: "404";
    value: {
      description: "Returned when the resource does not exist.";
      schema: {
        json_schema: {
          type: STRING;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

service JWTService {
  option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_tag) = {
    description: "JWT Service CRUD."
  };
  rpc CreateJWTToken(CreateJWTTokenRequest) returns (CreateJWTTokenResponse) {}
  rpc UpdateJWTToken(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/jwt/update"
      body: "*"
    }; 
  }
  rpc DeleteJWTToken(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

message CreateJWTTokenRequest {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
}
message CreateJWTTokenResponse {
  string jwt = 1;
}
```

I'm using bazel to create the BUILD files. So running `bazel run //:gazelle` creates the following BUILD.bazel file in the proto/service-0 directory:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:def.bzl", "go_proto_library")

proto_library(
    name = "0_proto",
    srcs = ["service-0.proto"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_google_protobuf//:empty_proto",
        "@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_proto",
        "//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto",
    ],
)

go_proto_library(
    name = "0_go_proto",
    compilers = ["@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:go_grpc"],
    importpath = "gitlab.example.de/tool/proto/service-0",
    proto = ":0_proto",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto",
        "//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto",
    ],
)

go_library(
    name = "service-0",
    embed = [":0_go_proto"],
    importpath = "gitlab.example.de/tool/proto/service-0",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Now running `bazel build //proto/service-0:service-0` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/Documents/tool/proto/service-0/BUILD.bazel:16:1: no such package 'protoc-gen-swagger/options': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
```

So I add the following line to the root BUILD.bazel file how it is described [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#dependency-resolution):

```
# gazelle:resolve proto protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto @grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto
```

to let gazelle generate `@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto` instead of `//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto`
This works without any problem.

**Now how do I create the go-grpc files with bazel which I need to develop the service?**

Running `bazel build //proto/service-0:0_go_proto` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/Documents/tool/proto/service-0/BUILD.bazel:16:1: in deps attribute of go_proto_library rule //proto/service-0:0_go_proto: '@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto' does not have mandatory providers: 'GoLibrary'
```

So for development it should be possible to generate the go-grpc files with bazel so that the generated grpc files are stored at the proto/service-x/ directories.

In addition I'm using grpc-gateway. So I added the following lines to the `BUILD.bazel` file in the `service-0` directory how it is described [here](https://github.com/rules-proto-grpc/rules_proto_grpc/blob/master/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/README.md):

```
load("@rules_proto_grpc//github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway:defs.bzl", "gateway_grpc_compile", "gateway_grpc_library", "gateway_swagger_compile")

gateway_grpc_compile(
    name = "0_gateway_grpc",
    verbose = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":0_proto"],
)

gateway_swagger_compile(
    name = "0_gateway_swagger_grpc",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":0_proto"],
)

gateway_grpc_library(
    name = "0_gateway_library",
    importpath = "gitlab.example.de/tool/proto/0",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":0_proto"],
)
```

Running `bazel build :0_gateway_swagger_grpc` gives the following output:

```
INFO: Invocation ID: 3b88f546-f09a-49d7-b238-0d41d98b9aa6
INFO: Analyzed target //proto/service-0:0_gateway_swagger_grpc (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //proto/service-0:0_gateway_swagger_grpc up-to-date:
  dist/bin/proto/service-0/0_gateway_swagger_grpc/proto/service-0/service-0.swagger.json
  dist/bin/proto/service-0/0_gateway_swagger_grpc/protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.swagger.json
  dist/bin/proto/service-0/0_gateway_swagger_grpc/protoc-gen-swagger/options/openapiv2.swagger.json
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.092s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

This works without any problems. But when I try to generate the gateway files with `bazel build :0_gateway_grpc` I get the following errors:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //proto/service-0:0_gateway_grpc (3 packages loaded, 17 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling protoc outputs for grpc_gateway_plugin plugin:
WARNING: Package "github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/generator" is deprecated.
    A future release of golang/protobuf will delete this package,
    which has long been excluded from the compatibility promise.

INFO: From Compiling protoc outputs for grpc_gateway_plugin plugin:
WARNING: Package "github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/generator" is deprecated.
    A future release of golang/protobuf will delete this package,
    which has long been excluded from the compatibility promise.

ERROR: /home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/81e1d15aef6baed1975edd8b4c490e5b/external/grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway/protoc-gen-swagger/options/BUILD.bazel:20:1: output 'external/grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway/protoc-gen-swagger/options/options_proto/gateway_grpc_compile_aspect_verb1/protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.pb.gw.go' was not created
ERROR: /home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/81e1d15aef6baed1975edd8b4c490e5b/external/grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway/protoc-gen-swagger/options/BUILD.bazel:20:1: output 'external/grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway/protoc-gen-swagger/options/options_proto/gateway_grpc_compile_aspect_verb1/protoc-gen-swagger/options/openapiv2.pb.gw.go' was not created
ERROR: /home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/81e1d15aef6baed1975edd8b4c490e5b/external/grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway/protoc-gen-swagger/options/BUILD.bazel:20:1: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //proto/service-0:0_gateway_grpc failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.243s, Critical Path: 0.11s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**So how can I fix this? And when this is fixed how can I make bazel to create/copy the files for development also in the proto/service-x directories?**

I'm using [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) and bazel version `3.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've already found a solution, but I'm trying to do something similar, and your notes were helpful to me.

Regarding this error:

```
ERROR: /home/Documents/tool/proto/service-0/BUILD.bazel:16:1: in deps attribute of go_proto_library rule //proto/service-0:0_go_proto: '@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-swagger/options:options_proto' does not have mandatory providers: 'GoLibrary'
```

I found that you can fix this with a second `gazelle:resolve` directive which includes the `import-lang` argument. Specifically:

```
 gazelle:resolve proto go protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto @grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-openapiv2/options:options_go_proto
```

I didn't encounter the other error you described.